# \hfill between lines

Tags: plain-tex, glue

In the first paragraph put out by the following programme, `dolor` is
set at the right margin.  In the second, this doesn't happen, presumably
because when the `\hfill` happens we are still on the first line.

```
\hsize 4in

lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ip
\hfill dolor

lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ip
\hfill dolor

lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ip%
\break\null
\hfill dolor

lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
\break\null
\hfill dolor

\bye
```

[image: output]

How can I ensure that `dolor` is set at the right margin, regardless of
the position at which it occurs?  That is, how can I get the effect of
the third paragraph, but not that of the fourth (with an extra line
break) if the length of the text before dolor is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well described in the TeXbook (look for Bourbaki in the index).

```
\def\NN#1{\leavevmode\llap{\hbox to\parindent{#1\hss}}\ignorespaces} % for reference

\def\signed#1{{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil#1%
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}

\hsize 4in

\NN1
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ip
\signed{dolor}

\NN2
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ip
\signed{dolor}

\NN3
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ip%
\signed{dolor}

\NN4
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
l
\signed{dolor}

\NN5
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lo
\signed{dolor}

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\leavevmode\penalty50\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill dolor
```

should add non discardable fill glue without forcing a line break.